# External layout on custom module report odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I want add external layout header and footer on my custome report.

My custom module:

```
class my_module(osv.osv):
    _name = "my.module"
    _description = "my module"
    _columns = {
           'name': fields.char('Name',size=256),
           'date': fields.date('Date', select=True),
           'user': fields.many2one('res.users', 'User', select=True, track_visibility='onchange'),
           'description':fields.html('Description'),
          }
```

In report I'm add line **external_layout** from project module:

```
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
<t t-call="report.external_layout">
        <t t-set="doc" t-value="doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})" />
<div class="page">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center"><h2><b>MY REPORT</b></h2></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

When open report get error:

```
 Error message:

"'my.module' object has no attribute 'partner_id'" while evaluating
"doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add *partner_id* field into your model.

For example:

```
'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner', required=1)
```

Don't forget to add *partner_id* in view file.

Afterwards, restart Odoo server and upgrade your module.